# Is there a built in way to use ReportsChart component in a custom Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, reports-api, report-chart, analytics-reportchart

I have a Visualforce page that displays Report Charts dynamically for end users, base don Report Id selection.

I am looking to replicate same kind of function in Lightning Component, but it seems there is built in way that I could find in documentation to utilize the ReportsChart component in a custom Lightning Component.

Is that right?

I know there is ChartsJS external library available, but with that I've to build component data source js myself, and I would like to use the standard native ReportChart to display with Lightning CSS Styling automatically. Plus ChartsJS requires me to generate full data source javascript array for each chart, which in my use case is not possible, since I want the Report Chart to display by supplying in Report ID and report filter.

Can someone suggest if this ReportsChart component is coming for developers to use in future or I missed it in documentation somewhere :-) ...

Comment: did you get an answer for your question? I need to do the same thing.

Comment: Nopes. Nothing on it yet.